# python flask socket not working when I join a room

Tags: python, reactjs, api, sockets, flask

I'm setting up a project, but I'm facing a problem that has been frustrating me for about 2 days. I am creating a kind of mini game in my app for players to play. When I use sockets to create a real-time broadcast communication tunnel it works pretty well.

```py
@socketio.on("createBattleground")
def createBattleground(data):
    emit('responseCreateBattleground', {"data": data}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("joinBattleground")
def on_joinBattleground(data):
    emit('responseJoinBattleground', {"data": data}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("leaveBattleground")
def on_leaveBattleground(data):
    emit('responseLeaveBattleground', {"data": data}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("banBattleground")
def on_banBattleground(data):
    emit('responseBanBattleground', {"data": data}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("unbanBattleground")
def on_unbanBattleground(data):
    emit('responseUnbanBattleground', {"data": data}, broadcast=True)
```

The example below will show you that things work in real time correctly with the broadcast method.

[Example of socket.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4LWu.gif)

But when I try to organize this with the room system, it doesn't work anymore. I changed the code to :

```py
@socketio.on("createBattleground")
def createBattleground(data):
    GetRoomObject = int(data["data"]["Information"]["OwnerId"])
    join_room(GetRoomObject)
    emit('responseCreateBattleground', {"data": data}, room=GetRoomObject)

@socketio.on("joinBattleground")
def on_joinBattleground(data):
    GetRoomObject = int(data["data"]["Information"]["OwnerId"])
    join_room(GetRoomObject)
    emit('responseJoinBattleground', {"data": data}, room=GetRoomObject)
```

OwnerId is just the game creator, every user who wants to join a game, players will join the game creator id as a room.

Now if I try to do the same above again, it won't work anymore, I don't know why the socket is unable to send data back to the client (React).

As you can see, the part on the right is the player who wants to join the game and the page on the left is the Owner of the game, he does not receive any update of the presence of the player.

I would be very happy if I can have logical explanations or advice.

[Example of socket 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTaHC.gif)

Comment: Can you share the definition of join_room. Also check in the debugger if the value of GetRoomObject is what you expect when you pull it out of the data dict, and after whatever happens in join_room. Finally the main difference between your working and non working code is you're not setting broadcast to True and you're passing the GetRoomObject parameter. I would get a minimum working example of both those things working on their own to verify it's not your problem.

Comment: Here is the link for the join_room function.

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#rooms

And I tested well, and indeed it does return the value to me in the output. So I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: My goal is not to broadcast to everyone, because otherwise it will cause a lot of problems if I create another part, the values ​​will be interchanged, and it will be a mess. (I tried). That's why now I try to filter with the room system so that each player joins a game according to the user id of the creator of the game.

Comment: If your python code is performing as you'd expect, maybe the issue is with the reactjs code? Is it listening for the responseCreateBattleground or responseJoinBattleground signal/events?

Comment: I solved my problem, the problem was indeed in React, thanks for helping me anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear it, best of luck with the rest of your project, looks interesting.